# AHK how to remap Middle Mouse Scroll Click to Left Click + Right Click?

Tags: autohotkey

In AHK, I want to remap Middle Mouse Scroll Click to Left Click + Right Click. Tried this syntax, but doesn't work:

```
LButton+Rbutton::MButton
```

Please help!

Comment: Your question and your "solution" are the opposite. "Remap the middle mouse button to Left Click + Right click" means that when you press the middle mouse button, AutoHotKey then sends a Left Click and Right click. Your solution "looks" to do the opposite.